# Warning after redirect to another route in React Router

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I am new in React and I have one question about, Redirect router, and mounted component, beacause I am getting warnings. Please look on may component:

```
class Activation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super()
    this.token = props.match.params.id
    this.state = {
        fadeOn: false
    }
 }
 componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/api/activate/' + this.token, {
        method: 'PUT'
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((message)=>{
        if(message.success){
            this.setState({
                fadeOn: true,
                msg: message.message
            })  
        } else {
            this.setState({
                fadeOn: true,
                errMsg: message.message
            })  
        }
    })
}
render(){
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <img className="rabbit" src={rabbit}/>
                <Fade in={this.state.fadeOn}>
                    {this.state.msg?
                        <Alert bsStyle="success" className="activeAlert">{this.state.msg}</Alert>
                        :
                        <Alert bsStyle="danger" className="activeAlert">{this.state.errMsg}</Alert> 
                    }
                </Fade>
            </Row>
            <Redirect to="/"/>
        </Grid>

    )
  }
}
export default Activation
```

Component in path="/"

```
class Users extends Component {
 render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <h1>Users page!!!</h1>
  </div>
  );
 }
}
export default Users;
```

And my goal is redirect user after activate his account. Everything work fine but after redirection I get following warning: `Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method`. Could you explain me what I did wrong, and how my my component?

Comment: Pls add the code of the component which is to be displayed in path, `"/"`

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in the initial render itself you are redirecting to "/" and then in componentDidMount you are setting the state. So,

In the constructor set the state as,

```
this.state = {
        fadeOn: false,
        activationComplete: false ,
    }
```

And in the `.then` of fetch, you should set the state as,

```
this.setState({
                fadeOn: true,
                msg: message.message,
                activationComplete:true
            })
```

then, in the render, replace the existing redirect statement with,

```
render(){
    if(this.state.activationComplete)
      return <Redirect to="/"/>
    else
      return (
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <img className="rabbit" src={rabbit}/>
                <Fade in={this.state.fadeOn}>
                    {this.state.msg?
                        <Alert bsStyle="success" className="activeAlert">{this.state.msg}</Alert>
                        :
                        <Alert bsStyle="danger" className="activeAlert">{this.state.errMsg}</Alert> 
                    }
                </Fade>
            </Row>

        </Grid>

    )
  }
```